# Are my ASUS ROG G751JL "CPU" and "Motherboard" temperatures high?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, cooling, temperature

I need info on how safe are these temperatures, and what is the temperature i should not have on my **asus rog G751JL laptop**.

While on battery, when i run (scenario) Rise of the Tomb Raider, my temperatures of motherboard and CPU are mostly fine (around) 60 C (but FPS also drops to 30ish...)
But when i connect it to charger, and i start the game, frame rate gets up to 50ish, and **CPU** alongside with my Motherboard gets **70C +**, **motherboard** sometimes even touches **82ish C**, and thats were my jets start to really rock the heat out of it.

Do i have reason to fear? I mean, i know it's a gaming laptop, and they must have designed it to sustain some higher temperatures, but i don't know what are safe temperatures for it.
Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're on battery, the computer is likely throttling a little bit to conserve battery life.  This would result in lower temps and lower FPS.  Once plugged in it removes the throttling, raising the temps and FPS (plus it probably has charging heat added in as well).

As for what temps are too high, you would have to check with the manufacturer of the laptop to be sure, but from the laptop model number, I'm guessing that you have an Intel i7-4720HQ processor, which [according to Intel, has a max temp of 100°C](http://ark.intel.com/products/78934/Intel-Core-i7-4720HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz).  There should be a thermal cutoff in the processor and/or motherboard preventing it from passing this temp, and thus probably preventing any thermal damage.

In my experience, laptop manufacturers value quiet performance over low heat, so they keep the fans off or on low speed as long as possible.  If you want to preemptively speed up your fans, you might try installing [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).  For most machines, this will allow you to set your own temps for when to turn on the fan(s), and you can even force them to be on at all times.

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. Actually my CPU is i7-4750HQ.
It's my first laptop so that's why i get confused on these stuff...
That program SpeedFan you are talking about, it's to be takne lightly? I mean, i tried to look in BIOS for fan options, but somehow my bios is like in win7, the casual, and therefore i couldn't find those "advanced" options...
Im trying to say, is that SpeedFan compatible with my laptop? So just anyone can mess around with theyr fans?

Comment: The 4750HQ still has a max of 100 so you should be fine.  As for SpeedFan, you could potentially use it to do harm to the system (disabling fans), but I don't know if the underlying manufacturer controls would allow that.  The defaults for SpeedFan don't actually change fan speeds, just lets you see all the temps and RPMs.  You can set your own lower temps at which it should ramp up the fans.  I used it on an old laptop that I thought had too high of temps when running.

Comment: Hmm alrighty, i'll look for it.
Just one more thingy. Is there a way to find out safe temperature numbers for my motherboard? You said about my CPU, but i'm unable to find these numbers for motherboard, since it gets high few celsius more than CPU...

Comment: You'd have to look on the manufacturer's site or contact them directly.  I would imagine that it's about the same as the processor, since Intel would have provided them with the specs about the processor they were going to use.  I think as long as you keep the vents on the laptop clear of dust you probably will not exceed any temp that could cause damage, but that's just my "common sense" guess.